# Vue.js lifecycle hooks

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

I was sure that the lifecycle hooks in Vue were 8 (beforeCreate, created, beforeMount, mounted, beforeUpdate, updated, beforeDestroy, destroyed) but today I found out(https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#activated) that there are 3 more:

• **activated**

• **deactivated**

• **error captured**

Somebody can explain how these 3 work? Is possible to test them with a console.log? (Just to understand when they are called)

Comment: Of course did you?

Comment: I didn't understand when they are called, why wouldn't you explain me?

Answer (score 4):

First, a little context:

In Vue 2.0+, there is a built-in component called `<keep-alive>` that takes the child element inside it and keeps it alive in memory as a cached component. Normally, Vue would reuse a component if its props change, but maybe the component is very complex and is slow to update. You could wrap it with `<keep-alive>` and the component would be cached for the props provided to it.

When a component inside a `<keep-alive>` is updated, the `activated` life-cycle hook is called. When that component is cached and set aside, the `deactivated` life-cycle hook is called.

The `errorCaptured` life-cycle hook was added in Vue 2.5.0 and is called whenever an error is captured by a descendent component. So, if you have a component called A that has a child component called B, and that has a child component called C, then if C captures and error, the `errorCaptured` life-cycle hook will be called on both A and B.

These hooks all work the same as any other hook, so use them the same way.

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {}
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log('mounted hook called')
    },
    errorCaptured(err, vm, info) {
      console.log('error captured in component', vm)
      console.error(err)
      console.log('error info:', info)
    },
    activated() {
      console.log('cached component is being used again')
    },
    deactivated() {
      console.log('component is being kept alive in cache for now')
    }
}
```

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#activated
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#deactivated
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorCaptured

Comment: I tried like that but the ```console.log()``` of the ```activated``` and ```deactiveted``` is not showing. You can see it here https://codepen.io/93lucasp/pen/VwZdQyz

Comment: You can see here also what I tried https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-js-lifecycle-hooks/74119/7 but no way to show that console.log()

Comment: I'm looking at your codepen and it is showing `activated()` and `deactivate()` in the console when switching between component 1 and component 2.

Comment: I changed, I found out!

Comment: Great. Go ahead and accept the answer and we can all move along. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's already late for this answer but someone might also looking answer for
the problem. Vue.js disable's console.log function by default, so we have to enable it.

Just put `"rules": { "no-console": "off",}` on package.json

Cheers